# How to make the click logo appear without a href in css/html?

Tags: css, html, click

Basically I want to make normal text clickable, but with that click mouse logo popping up! I can make the text clickable using 'onclick' but this doesn't give the text that hover like click logo.

Sorry for my noobiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS property `cursor: pointer;` to achieve desired result.

*Edit:* If you want to apply other styles when the user hovers over the text, then add selector to include pseudo selector `:hover` to style during mouse over.

Comment: No need for hover, actually. `cursor` implies hover.

Comment: Lawls yeah I realize that afterwards, they're the same behaviour :P

Answer (score 0):

You simply set the cursor property on the parent element.

```
span { cursor: pointer; }
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XxrMM/